# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _createStore.default) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, gatsby

I am switching my redux-react app to gatsby app , I am facing this issue [image]

and I cannot see the pages anymore.
I've tried to follow these instructions : https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-redux
yet I get this problem.
createStore.js :

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import createSagaMiddle from 'redux-saga'
import rootSaga from './rootSaga'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddle()
export const middlewares = [thunk,sagaMiddleware,logger];
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
export default store;
```

rootReducer.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import userReducer from './User/user.reducer'
export default combineReducers({
    user: userReducer
})
```

wrap-with-provider.js:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import   { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import  store from './src/state/createStore'
const wrapWithProvider = ({ element }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>{element}</Provider>
);
export default wrapWithProvider
```

and gatsby-ssr.js / gatsby-browser.js:

```
import wrapWithProvider from "./wrap-with-provider"
export const wrapRootElement = wrapWithProvider
```

what probably could be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I removed brackets({}) in import and that fixed my problem. You can try this: import createStore from 'redux'